# Copy of InputStream blocks with Jetty HTTP client using an InputStreamResponseListener

Tags: java, jetty

Im am using Jetty 9.4.8 HTTP client and want to write a stream of incoming data to a file. Currently I am using an InputStreamResponseListener and IOUtils.copy(..) writing to a FileOutputStream. I have also tried Files.copy().

```
InputStreamResponseListener streamResponseListener = new InputStreamResponseListener();

request.send(streamResponseListener);

if(streamResponseListener.get(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES).getStatus() == 200) {
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        TMP_FILE.toFile().createNewFile();
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(TMP_FILE.toFile());
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        this.getLogService().log(..)
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(outputStream);
    }

    // NOT REACHED IN CASE InputStream is BLOCKED FOR SOME REASON
}
```

However, the copy methods seem to block after all bytes have been received. Why could this happen and how can I avoid this?

Headers of the HTTP content requested:

```
Date: Wed, 23 May 2018 16:46:06 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".."
Content-Length: 613970044
Server: Jetty(9.4.8.v20171121)
```

IOUtils from Apache Commons IO Version 2.4

Comment: Can you post your code snippet?

Comment: I have added a code snipped. This is as similar as possible to my scenario. I am using a wrapper class for several objects.

Comment: btw. the onSuccess() method is called by Jetty. Originally I had the problem, that with onSuccess() called the stream was not fully written.

Comment: I faced a similar problem today, If you call something off the jetty server on the same thread, the server will block until the callback is completed

Comment: More likely an EOF is missing somewhere, Its difficult to figure out without the calling code, lets see if someone else figures this out.

Comment: Using wget for the same HTTP resource works fine. My server does send all the content and it seems to be possible to detect the end of the stream. However, I need to know when and in which order getInputStream() and onSuccess() are invoked and in which cases an InputStream could block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example of your codebase, using only Java and Jetty.

This is requesting content from a server that is known to comply with the HTTP spec.

```java
package demo.jettyclient;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient;
import org.eclipse.jetty.client.api.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.client.api.Response;
import org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.InputStreamResponseListener;
import org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpStatus;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.IO;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.StringUtil;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory;

public class DownloadUrl
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String uriString = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a1/Jetty_logo.png?download";

        if (args.length >= 1)
            uriString = args[0];

        URI srcUri = URI.create(uriString);

        SslContextFactory ssl = new SslContextFactory(true);

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(ssl);
        try
        {
            client.start();

            Request request = client.newRequest(srcUri);

            System.out.printf("Using HttpClient v%s%n", getHttpClientVersion());
            System.out.printf("Requesting: %s%n", srcUri);
            InputStreamResponseListener streamResponseListener = new InputStreamResponseListener();
            request.send(streamResponseListener);
            Response response = streamResponseListener.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            if (response.getStatus() != HttpStatus.OK_200)
            {
                throw new IOException(
                        String.format("Failed to GET URI [%d %s]: %s",
                                response.getStatus(),
                                response.getReason(),
                                srcUri));
            }

            Path tmpFile = Files.createTempFile("tmp", ".dl");

            try (InputStream inputStream = streamResponseListener.getInputStream();
                 OutputStream outputStream = Files.newOutputStream(tmpFile))
            {
                IO.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
            }

            System.out.printf("Downloaded %s%n", srcUri);
            System.out.printf("Destination: %s (%,d bytes)%n", tmpFile.toString(), Files.size(tmpFile));
        }
        finally
        {
            client.stop();
        }
    }

    private static String getHttpClientVersion()
    {
        ClassLoader cl = HttpClient.class.getClassLoader();

        // Attempt to use maven pom properties first
        String pomResource = "/META-INF/maven/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-client/pom.properties";
        URL url = cl.getResource(pomResource);
        if (url != null)
        {
            try (InputStream in = url.openStream())
            {
                Properties props = new Properties();
                props.load(in);
                String version = props.getProperty("version");
                if (StringUtil.isNotBlank(version))
                    return version;
            }
            catch (IOException ignore)
            {
            }
        }

        // Attempt to use META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
        String version = HttpClient.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
        if (StringUtil.isNotBlank(version))
            return version;

        return "<unknown>";
    }
}
```

When run, this results in ...

```
2018-05-23 10:52:08.401:INFO::main: Logging initialized @325ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
Using HttpClient v9.4.9.v20180320
Requesting: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a1/Jetty_logo.png?download
Downloaded https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a1/Jetty_logo.png?download
Destination: C:\Users\joakim\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2166600286896937563.dl (11,604 bytes)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

One (or more) of the following is likely causing your issue.

1. There is either something wrong with your server, not complying with the HTTP spec.
2. The HTTP exchange isn't complete yet (from the protocol point of view).  Capture the traffic and verify the behavior.
3. The IOUtil library you are using (you didn't say which one) has a bug.

The fact that wget (or curl) works is likely because they are not strict with Content-Length (per recommendations in RFC7230) and will display / download all content received until physical connection EOF/disconnect.   While the HTTP/1.1 protocol has a connection persistence and strict rules on when the request (and response) content ends.

Comment: Ok, thanks. My server is Jetty too :)! Currently I do not set a Content-Length. Does this explain the blocking? Is the Content-Length header mandatory?

Comment: If onSuccess() is invoked because the response succeeded, why does the input stream still block?

Comment: I am sorry, but it still blocks also with Content-Length header. I have added my response headers to the question.

Comment: IOUtils from Apache Commons IO Version 2.4, but it also occurs with java.nio.file.Files.copy().

Comment: onSuccess() is called, but copy of InputStream still blocks. Is this a bug?

Comment: Why does InputStreamResponseListener.Input not implement further methods of InputStream (e.g. available)?

Comment: Accepted the answer. However, InputStream is blocked in some cases when I use the InputStreamResponseListener object to handle the InputStream. IMHO this is a bug. I also think that onSuccess() should not be called by Jetty in case InputStream is not fully read or blocking. I will report a bug to the Jetty community.